When I run glab commands, it always asks me for my username?
Let's say I have a script with glab repo create,
mkdir foo;
cd foo;
git init;
glab repo create;

When I get to glab repo create it asks for my username,
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ecarroll/test-artifacts/foo/.git/
✓ Created repository Evan Carroll / foo on GitLab: https://gitlab.acme.net/evancarroll/foo
Username for 'https://gitlab.acme.net':

Why is this?

Git Credential Helper
For me the reasons was because in my ~/.git/config I had
[credential "https://gitlab.acme.net"]
    helper = 
    helper = !/usr/bin/glab auth git-credential

But I had installed glab to /usr/local/bin/glab (per Debian standards). Updating this path fixed it. I just removed the explicit qualification,
[credential "https://gitlab.acme.net"]
    helper = 
    helper = !glab auth git-credential

